# How does Twilio interface with Echo (Alexa) to transmit voice signals to and from another device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio, sip, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to build an Alexa voice skill which will enable users to place VoIP calls to another device (not an Echo device but a mobile or phone) through an existing voice network (not Twilio' infrastructure) with an Echo device. I am quite clear on the implementation logic in AWS Lambda to initiate call to the receiving end. But what I am not clear on is how this voice signal is interfaced with Echo. From intensive research it is evident that Amazon Alexa doesn't have an SIP client to receive SIP calls. Apparently, Twilio has managed to do this. It has used its existing APIs to make calls through Echo. Its not very clear on how Twilio has managed stream the voice call back to an Echo device. I looked at Alexa's SDK but SDK is supposed to be used with 3rd party hardware not on an existing Echo unit. If someone could give me a few areas/topics to read up, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Afaik, Twilio does not do "live" voice calls.  Their api allows you to specify some text and a phone number, and their service will call the number and read the message via TTS.  To do what you're describing would require a function in the echo/alexa APIs that creates an audio stream from the device to an arbitrary endpoint, and it doesn't look like such a function exists.

Comment: *"Apparently, Twilio has managed to do this."*  Please provide a link that describes the capability you are referring to.

Comment: @1.618, I am really for giving wrong information. As you mentioned Twilio has only managed to send voice and text MESSAGES not calls. Sending messages is quite straightforward. But Amazon has released Connect, a device which can be used to call phone numbers. Thanks guys. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Can we use Amazon Connect to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think we are facing the some problem. I am trying to combine the Twilio Autopilot with Echo Skill. I was trying to collect some info using echo skill and then put them to our routing system which based on the twilio, then create a call back phone call to connect with phone though echo, then merge back to twilo programable voice, then I had fully control. But, the problem is :

1. echo can not handle inbound call except alxe to alxe call (drop in call, using alex app)
2. echo skill can not trigger call function. so you can only send message not real time steaming, and twilio also don't have sdk for echo to support it

so if you want communicate though echo, the only way is set up a number in your alxe apple contact with a "", and the number should be twilio programmable phone number, then you can control the request. But I have to say this is useless! because you can not do any thing with alxe, it just become a speaker and mic. :>